# Manipulating raw packets to have NAT functionality

Tags: python, scapy

I want to implement a custom NAT in python, in terms of doing that I want to receive all client packets and modify them. Then forward them to another device.

I found `scapy` that can manipulate and send packets easily. But could not find a way to receive packets. So is it possible to receive packets then edit them like editing `source IP` and `destination IP` and read UDP headers and forward them and later forward the response packets?

Comment: Implementing NAT implies that you have two IP addresses configured (one for the internal network, the other for the external network) and others devices on the internal configured to use your internal IP as gateway.  Do you have that configured?

Comment: Not exactly for now all devices on the same network. Suppose I have device with IP 192.168.100.2 (client) that is connected to 192.168.100.3 (server) I want to simulate the nat on internal network so the client will send packets to 192.168.100.4 (NAT) and the NAT will change the source IP to  192.168.100.4 and destination IP to 192.168.100.3  and when the server response the NAT will change the source IP to  192.168.100.4 and destination IP to 192.168.100.2. Then later I will add the public IP part so servers will be behind this NAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the `sniff()` function of `scapy` to receive packets:

```
>>> help(sniff)
Sniff packets and return a list of packets.
Args:
    count: number of packets to capture. 0 means infinity.
    store: whether to store sniffed packets or discard them
    prn: function to apply to each packet. If something is returned, it
         is displayed.
         --Ex: prn = lambda x: x.summary()
    filter: BPF filter to apply.
    lfilter: Python function applied to each packet to determine if
             further action may be done.
             --Ex: lfilter = lambda x: x.haslayer(Padding)
    offline: PCAP file (or list of PCAP files) to read packets from,
             instead of sniffing them
    timeout: stop sniffing after a given time (default: None).
    L2socket: use the provided L2socket (default: use conf.L2listen).
    opened_socket: provide an object (or a list of objects) ready to use
                  .recv() on.
    stop_filter: Python function applied to each packet to determine if
                 we have to stop the capture after this packet.
                 --Ex: stop_filter = lambda x: x.haslayer(TCP)
    iface: interface or list of interfaces (default: None for sniffing
           on all interfaces).
    monitor: use monitor mode. May not be available on all OS
    started_callback: called as soon as the sniffer starts sniffing
                      (default: None).
The iface, offline and opened_socket parameters can be either an
element, a list of elements, or a dict object mapping an element to a
label (see examples below).
Examples:
  >>> sniff(filter="arp")
  >>> sniff(lfilter=lambda pkt: ARP in pkt)
  >>> sniff(iface="eth0", prn=Packet.summary)
  >>> sniff(iface=["eth0", "mon0"],
  ...       prn=lambda pkt: "%s: %s" % (pkt.sniffed_on,
  ...                                   pkt.summary()))
  >>> sniff(iface={"eth0": "Ethernet", "mon0": "Wifi"},
  ...       prn=lambda pkt: "%s: %s" % (pkt.sniffed_on,
  ...                                   pkt.summary()))
```

The `prn` argument especially, allows you to perform an action on each received packet. They are many great tutorials out there

Based on your comment, here is a sample:

```
 def _process(pkt):
      if IP in pkt:
           pkt[IP].dst = "y.y.y.y"
           pkt[Ether].dst = None  # Force scapy to re-calculate the MAC dst
           sendp(pkt)  # send the packet
 sniff(iface="eth0", prn=_process)
```

Comment: I dont want to sniff the client will send the packet directly to device and the respones should be from the device is there a way to work on raw packet level and contruct scapy packet using it.

Comment: Sorry, your comment is really hard to understand :/ sniff() allows to receive packets. You can edit them if you want, change stuff, then send them back. All of this can be done "on-the-go" with the prn argument.

Comment: I not sure how does sniff work. Suppose I have a machine with IP x and and server with IP y.  The client sends a packet to x then IP x will forward it to IP y machine. How IP x will sniff this packet?

Comment: Updated the answer